# Adding todo inside a caption

Tags: todonotes

I am using the `todonotes` package and I wanted to add a note inside a caption like:

```
\caption{This is the section heading\todo{We should rethink the section title.}}
```

However, this is throwing the “Not in outer par mode” error. I understand why, but I wonder if there is a way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this works also for captions outside figures... http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256802/124842

Comment: A workround is described in the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415323/153215

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know `\todo` does not work in a caption, but `\todo[inline]` will do, however, the remark text is not in the margin!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{This is the section heading\todo[inline]{We should rethink the section title.}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should have tried that first. Thanks. Not as good as having it at the margin, but it'll do for now.

Comment: @ozsu: Well, or http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t's solution with LuaLaTeX....

Comment: I now need to add a todo inside a section header -- can that be done? The method proposed by Christian Hupfer did not work.

Comment: Actually, I thought that having this additional question here would be confusing, so I posted a separate question for this at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355628/adding-todo-inside-section-title

Comment: The method does not work because you can't write the `\todo` code into the ToC, which would be the case for `\section{foo \todo[inline]{some text}}`

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be useful, but the `luatodonotes` package works in captions. It requires the use of `lualatex` for compiling the document though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatodonotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is the section heading\todo{We should rethink the section title.}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I can't move to luatex for this project, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a todo (not only todo[inline], but todo in margins) inside floating environments (like table, figure, etc). You just need to add the following patch:

```latex
\usepackage{marginnote}
\let\marginpar\marginnote
```

Source: the todonotes package manual http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf section 1.6.9.

I have tested your code with this patch and it works correctly. Although 4 years have passed since this question was asked I post the solution here in case someone need it in the future, like myself today.