# Adding \todo inside section title

Tags: todonotes

I am using the [`todonotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) package and I wanted to add a note inside a section title like:

```
\section{This is the section heading\todo{We should rethink the section title.}}
```

However, this is throwing the “Not in outer par mode” error. I understand why, but I wonder if there is a way to do this.

I had previously asked about putting todo inside a caption, and the proposed solution of `\todo[inline]{...}` works in that case, but not inside `\section{...}`

EDIT: After some help, I realized that the error is in the generation of the table of contents. Here is a MWP:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\long\def\intodo#1{\todo[inline]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Another Section Name \intodo{We should rethink the section title for this as well.}}

\end{document}
```

The error that I get is:

```
./test.toc:2: Leaders not followed by proper glue.
<to be read again> 
                   \hfill 
l.2 ...e]{We should rethink the section title}}{3}
```

Comment: Please add a MWE. The following works fine: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\section{This is the section heading\todo{We should rethink the section title.}}
bla
\end{document} 
`

Comment: The `inline` option works for me, please see my answer.

Comment: You can actually use the `\todo` command in the `\section` macros etc. unless it is not written to the ToC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to Fran's idea, with a macro, but redefining it in the ToC to disable its meaning there, such that `\section[short title]{Other \todo}` is not needed (but possible).

In order to get nice output in the ToC, the `\intodo` command should be robust.

The `inline` option is not necessary in this approach, since the ToDo - Content does not enter the `ToC` area.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\intodo}[1]{%
  \todo[inline]{#1}%
}

\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\renewcommand{\protect\intodo}[1]{}}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section Name 
\intodo{We should rethink the section title}}
Some text 
\section{Another Section Name\intodo{We should rethink the section title for this as well.}}
More some text 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the output if the `inline` option is not used:

[image]

A variant using the fact that the TOC is typeset in a group to begin with: (proposed by @egreg)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd\intodo[1]{\todo[inline]{#1}}

\makeatletter
% fix \intodo so it does nothing in the TOC
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}
  {\begingroup}
  {\begingroup\let\intodo\@gobble}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Another Section Name \intodo{We should rethink the section title for this as well.}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `inline` version is working fine, but I cannot get it to work without the `inline` option. Can you help with the definition, if you don't mind? For example, how to define a `rtodo` as a robust `todo` without the inline option. Thanks much.

Comment: @oszu: Try `\DeclareRobustCommand{\rtodo}[1]{\todo{#1}}`

Comment: Thanks, I did that. I also added 
`\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\renewcommand{\protect\rtodo}[1]{}}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
}`

But it is throwing the following error not in the first paragraph in the section, but in the second paragraph:

`LaTeX Warning: Marginpar on page 9 moved.
./Chap11.tex:381: LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`

Comment: @ozsu: You can't use it in a `\caption` -- floating environments like figure etc. and `\marginpar` usage is contradictory. The robustness of a command won't help you here!

Comment: But the `DeclareRobustCommand{\intodo}[1]{\todo[inline]{#1}}` works. Is there any particular reason the non-inline version should not work?

Comment: Well, it is the same problem like in your other question: `\todo[inline]` does not use the margin par -- you can't refer to the margin par in a floating environment.

Comment: OK, thanks. In your original answer you had a version without the `inline` option, and I was trying to generate that but could not.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to insert the todo note in the table of contents as well.

Using `\section[title for toc]{title for text\intodo{note text}}` will work as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\long\def\intodo#1{\todo[inline]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[Section Name]{Section Name 
\intodo{We should rethink the section title}}
Some text 
\section[Another Section Name]{Another Section Name
\intodo{We should rethink the section title for this as well.}}
More some text 
\end{document}
```

BTW, I would start the `\intodo` macro with a `\bigskip`.

Comment: Nice Idea (+1) -- I have stolen your `\intodo` macro ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `inline` option. Or better yet, you may even define a macro for this if you have many *inline* todo's.

See the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\long\def\intodo#1{\todo[inline]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Name\todo[inline]{We should rethink the section title}}

\section{Another Section Name \intodo{We should rethink the section title for this as well.}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK,  I narrowed down my error. I am using the book class and here is the same example as @Masroor in book style

`\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\long\def\intodo#1{\todo[inline]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Another Section Name \intodo{We should rethink the section title for this as well.}}

\end{document}'

And the error is in the table of contents generation: 

`./test.toc:2: Leaders not followed by proper glue.
<to be read again> 
                   \hfill 
l.2 ...e]{We should rethink the section title}}{3}'

Comment: To make sure that this comment stuff is depicted properly, I edited my original question with the same content.