# Changes package in captions

Tags: captions, changes, trackchanges

**Is there a workaround to use the `changes` package inside captions?**

Here it is a minimal example, the annotations and changes work great everywhere except in captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\definechangesauthor[color=red]{JLM}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \added[id=JLM,comment={lipsum, lipsum}]{dolor sit amet}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer luctus molestie hendrerit. Nullam id consequat turpis. 

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    MyPictureHere
    \caption{Caption \added[id=JLM,comment={lipsum, lipsum}]{dolor sit amet}}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.11 ...comment={lipsum, lipsum}]{dolor sit amet}}
                                                  
You've lost some text.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@marbox 
                    
l.11 ...comment={lipsum, lipsum}]{dolor sit amet}}
```

---

I tried @UlrikeFischer workaround (add `\usepackage{marginnote}\let\marginpar\marginnote`), and it works in simple documents.
In more realistic documents it crams the comment bubbles.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: `\usepackage{marginnote}\let\marginpar\marginnote` could work.

Comment: Worked for me, is your tex system uptodate?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post. It works. A limitation I see in a realistic document is that it messes up the separation between bubbles everywhere else in the document. Do you know if there is a method to effectively use `\let\marginpar\marginnote` only inside captions. See my edit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I tried this `\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\let\marginpar\doifmodeelse{caption}{\oldmarginpar}{\marginnote}` but it didn't work.

Comment: How new is your latex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)`, but as I said: your solution works for simple documents but it messes up the vertical spacing of bubbles in general. Maybe there is a way substitute the `marginpar`/`marginnote` only when stricktly necessary (inside captions).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, to be extra correct, I took these screenshots in an Overleaf document using `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)`

Comment: Pity, too old to use the new hooks. Well simply write the let-command directly  before the caption if you want to use a change command there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. So in a newer version I wouldn’t see this problem? What version do you have? Do I let back and forth between definitions before and after the caption?

Comment: you would get the problems there too, but newer latex has more tools to smuggle code in.  if the caption is at the end of the figure you don't need to reset the command, the `\end{figure}` will do it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is using margin notes in the caption environment, in this case via the *todo* package.

You could try another markup of comments, e.g. with

```
\usepackage[commentmarkup=uwave]{changes}
```

Or you define your own markup using *setcommentmarkup*:

```
\setcommentmarkup{{\IfIsColored{\color{authorcolor}}{} -- #1--}}
```

In that case you can try to use *todo*, see e.g. [Adding todo inside a caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355594/adding-todo-inside-a-caption) or other solutions.