# Adding a note (for tracking changes) to a changed picture in LaTex

Tags: graphics, todonotes, changes

I'm trying to add a note to go alongside my picture, so the other researcher reviewing my paper knows that I changed a picture. It's a double-column paper. I read that I could add a \todo note, which I already tried adding alongside the caption of the picture:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.80\textwidth]{diagramaheuristicasfluxonewnewnew}
  \caption{Heuristic development process.\todo[author=Reviewer, color=blue!20]{atualizei essa figura.}}
\end{figure*}
```

I also tried adding the \todo note inside a \minipage right after the picture:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.80\textwidth]{diagramaheuristicasfluxonewnewnew}
  \caption{Heuristic development process.\todo[author=Reviewer, color=blue!20]{atualizei essa figura.}}
\end{figure*}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \captionof*{figure}{\todo[author=Reviewer, color=blue!20]{atualizei essa figura.}}
\end{minipage}
```

I also tried adding the \todo note right before the picture:

```
\todo[author=phillip, color=blue!20]{figura mudada} 
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.80\textwidth]{diagramaheuristicasfluxonewnewnew}
  \caption{Heuristic development process.}
\end{figure*}
```

But in all of these examples, my note appears one page before the picture. How can I force the note to appear right where the picture (or it's caption) is? I don't want to change the paper structure too much, as this note is supposed to be just for revision control, just between me and the other researcher.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to put a `todo` is to include it as inline below the `caption` command. Check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/cannot-use-inline-todonotes-in-a-figure-caption However, if its just a note on the margin, you could create a `tikz` node with `remember, overlay` option to add it manually on the side of the image. Do note that changes in the image positions mean that the note needs to be repositioned.

Comment: Or maybe use other packages like `background` or `marginnote`

Comment: It's difficult to help with just fragments of code, but you probably need to put it inside the `figure` environment, since that can move. (But not in the argument of `\caption`.)